# background image is less then the container width, tried many ways to fit it to full width, failed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap for design. two rows are in the container. the second row contains the background picture.[here the two rows. the images is slightly less then the full width.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l7hW.jpg)

Comment: Bootstrap rows have 15px padding on both sides. Try removing that.
But, I would suggest you apply the image in the background using CSS.

Comment: thanks jiya. i  already set padding to 0. you mean to use inline css instead of bootstrap class?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_hero
Refer this example

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you're looking for is [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), more specifically `cover`.